# HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() , does every StatusCode besides 200 throws exception?

Tags: c#, http-status-codes, httpwebresponse

Calling GetResponse() on an httpWebRequest,
In all my testing i saw that this call throws WebException when the request fail.

My question is why is there a StatusCode property on the HttpWebResponse ?
It seems that the GetResponse() call will only return responses with status code 200 and throw otherwise.

And should i even bother looking if the StatusCode is not 200 ?
Assuming the only thing i can do with this information is throw exception myself ...

Comment: Please show a full code sample of your tests.

Comment: StatusCode 200 means everything is OK. if incase you dont know!

Comment: Check this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpstatuscode(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I tested manually with various faulty urls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entire 2xx range means that the operation has completed successfully. Status code 201 for instance, indicates that a new resource has been created.

See http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html for a list of all common status codes.